# EXCEL VBA Code to search cell for match to a list and delete if no match

Tags: excel, vba, list, contains

(pic link below for this example): The data starts on row "A11", one block of data is A11 to A14, I need to search that range to see if it contains a member name from a list on sheet 2, for example Erik Christensen, if the list on sheet 2 doesnt have that name I need to delete rows A11 thru A14 and continue to the next block. The list on sheet 2 will have a varying amount of members to check so that needs to be taken into consideration. Once all the rows have been processed, I need to sorth them back to start at row A11.Please see pic and I will be extremely thankful for any help.

[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WKb7.png)

Comment: I am a complete beginner in VBA and have been watching tuts for the last few days. I searched for examples until my fingers bled to no avail. Sorry for the poor explanation but if i had a better idea of what I actually needed I could have probably asked better. I haven't tried anything because of the lack of examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the below answer, I have made a few assumptions:

1. Your data will always start on row 11 of the first sheet in the
   workbook.
2. The search term will always be found in the second row, below
   Object:...
3. The data will always present in rows of 4, as shown in the picture,
   with End: in the 4th row.
4. The list of valid names is in column A (beginning on A1) of the
   second sheet in the workbook.
5. By "sorted back to start on row A11", I assume you mean that the
   remaining blocks of data should start on row A11 and continue to the
   end of the data, not that any actual sorting (i.e. by name) is
   required.

This code will loop through all blocks of data (beginning with the last one, since we are deleting rows). If any of the names in column A of the second sheet appear in the block of data, that block is skipped. Otherwise, if no names appear, that block is deleted.

```
Sub SearchAndDeleteList()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim LRow As Long
Dim LListRow As Long
Dim BMatch As Boolean

'Find last instance of "End:" in
LRow = Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Find(what:="End*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
'Find last non-blank row in column A of second sheet
LListRow = Sheets(2).Range("A:A").Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

If LRow >= 11 Then
    'Make sure there are at least 11 rows of data
    i = LRow
    'MsgBox "First checkpoint: Last row of data is " & LRow 'Comment out this line
    Do
        BMatch = False
        For j = 1 To LListRow
            'Test this block to see if the value from j appears in the second row of data
            If InStr(1, Sheets(1).Range("A" & i - 2).Value2, Sheets(2).Range("A" & j).Value2) > 0 Then
                BMatch = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        'Application.StatusBar = "Match status for row " & i & ": " & BMatch
        If Not BMatch Then
            'Loop backwards to find the starting row (no lower than 11)
            For j = i To 11 Step -1
                If Sheets(1).Range("A" & j).Value2 Like "Object:*" Then Exit For
            Next j
            Sheets(1).Rows(j & ":" & i).Delete
            i = j - 1
        Else
            'Find next block
            If i > 11 Then
                For j = i - 1 To 11 Step -1
                    If Sheets(1).Range("A" & j).Value2 Like "End:*" Then Exit For
                Next j
                i = j
            Else
                i = 10 'Force the loop to exit
            End If
        End If
        'Application.StatusBar = "Moving to row " & i
    Loop Until i < 11

    'Loop back through and delete any blank rows
    LRow = Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    'MsgBox "Second checkpoint: new last row of data is " & LRow
    For i = LRow To 11 Step -1
        If Sheets(1).Range("A" & i).Value2 = vbNullString Then Sheets(1).Rows(i).Delete
    Next i
End If

'Application.StatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This doesnt appear to work. After I run the macro, It leaves an object row (Object: 35.9510345,-85.7578430) at the last row and soesnt appear to sort to A11. Not sure whats going on here, hmm. It also deletes some of the people it should be keeping.

Comment: Check my edit - I forgot to have .Find search for "End*". Let me know if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Also, can you clarify what you mean by "sort to A11"? Can you post a picture of what you'd like the finished data to look like with an example list?

Comment: Data in rows A1 thru A10 should never change and the data blocks (Starting at object and ending with end)  should always start at A11.    Heres what I get when I search for 2 names. http://imgur.com/7ylFLif

Comment: By sort, I mean remove the blank rows from the deleted 4 row data blocks that dont match,  sorting out all the blank rows starting at A11.

Comment: Ah, I did not realize there could be blank rows in the data. I have amended the code; it will now delete each block from Object: to End: where the name does not appear 2 rows above the End: row. It will then loop back through again and delete any remaining blank rows.

Comment: Excel became non responsive when I ran this macro. I really appreciate the help so far!

Comment: OK; I cannot duplicate the nonresponsive issue on my end. I have added a number of debug checkpoints; can you try to run it again? Please take a screenshot of each message box and, if possible, note what the status bar (lower left corner of Excel) says before becoming nonresponsive.

Comment: It says ready, just get a spinning circle and a not responding message. I stepped through it and it seemed to work, but I didnt step it all the way throught that would take a while.

Comment: Can you post a sample workbook (the actual spreadsheet, not a picture)?

Comment: Ok I stepped through the last edit, it starts looping on a true, statement.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzeEd4JLOY-kTHdVM1FSRTBIcTA is the link to the file

Comment: The file is permission locked and requires me to request access. I have done so.

Comment: OK, I think I've finally gotten it. Tested on your workbook and it works great - let me know if this edit is the one.

Comment: Youre the man!, That worked perfectly. Thanks for being patient with a noob :)

Comment: Awesome! We've all been there, my friend.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Nick's cracking actual OP's needs, I hereby propose a solution that should be more maintainable and/or changeable as per Op's future needs

```
Option Explicit

Sub SearchAndDeleteList2()

Dim dataSht As Worksheet
Dim dataRng As Range, namesRng As Range, cell As Range, rangeToDelete As Range
Dim firstAddress As String


'------------------------------
' setting stuff - begin
Set dataSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1Data") '<== change 'data' sheet as per your needs
With dataSht
    Set dataRng = .Range("A11:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)
End With
If dataRng.Rows(1).row < 11 Then Exit Sub

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2Names") '<== change 'names' sheet as per your needs
    Set namesRng = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)
End With

Call ApplicationSet(False, False, xlCalculationManual, False)
' setting stuff - end
'------------------------------


'------------------------------
' core code - begin
Set cell = dataRng.Find("End:", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
If Not cell Is Nothing Then
    firstAddress = cell.Address
    Do
        If Not MyMatch(GetName(cell.Offset(-2)), namesRng) Then Call UpdateRngToDelete(rangeToDelete, dataSht.Rows(cell.row).Offset(-3).Resize(4))

        Set cell = dataRng.FindNext(cell)
    Loop While cell.Address <> firstAddress

    rangeToDelete.Delete
End If
' core code - end
'------------------------------


Call ApplicationSet(True, True, xlCalculationAutomatic, True)

End Sub


Function GetName(cell As Range) As String
Dim iIni As Integer
Dim iEnd As Integer

iIni = InStr(cell.value, """") '<== the 'name' is always preceeded by '"' character
iEnd = InStr(cell.value, "\")  '<== the 'name' is always follwed by '/' character

GetName = Mid(cell.value, iIni + 1, iEnd - iIni - 1)

End Function


Sub UpdateRngToDelete(baseRng As Range, toBeAddedRng As Range)

If baseRng Is Nothing Then
    Set baseRng = toBeAddedRng
Else
    Set baseRng = Union(baseRng, toBeAddedRng)
End If

End Sub


Function MyMatch(value As String, rng As Range) As Boolean

MyMatch = Not IsError(Application.Match(value, rng, 0))

End Function
```

using separate functions or subs makes it easier (and faster!) to keep control and debug future code changes

Comment: Kudos - love your solution!